# Is an anti-Muslim backlash an explicit policy goal of ISIS?

Tags: war, islam, isis

Several commentators have claimed that ISIS (aka IS, ISIL or Daesh) has an explicit goal of triggering an anti-Muslim backlash from the West, thus encouraging moderate Muslims to become more extremist.

For example, Australia commentator [Waleed Aly](http://www.mamamia.com.au/news/waleed-aly-isil/) said:

> Because this evil organisation has it in their heads that if they can make Muslims the enemy of the West, then Muslims in France and England and America and here in Australia will have nowhere to turn but to ISIL.

On Twitter, [Iyad El-Baghdadi](https://twitter.com/iyad_elbaghdadi/status/665337881351729152) warns:

> ISIS's goal from their own publication. A black & white world. What they call "grayzone" is our coexistence zone.

In evidence, he excerpts an image from Issue 7 of Dabiq, an ISIS publication.   ([Copy hosted by Clarion project, NSFW, disturbing images](http://media.clarionproject.org/files/islamic-state/islamic-state-dabiq-magazine-issue-7-from-hypocrisy-to-apostasy.pdf)):

> [image: The extinction of the gray zone]

Is this plan - to recruit disenfranchised Muslims by first triggering an over-reaction against Muslims from the West - representative of stated ISIS policy goals, or this an odd outlier?

Comment: Since the question is on hold I can't answer, but if someone wants to pick up the ball and run with it if it's reopened, Atlantic's "What does ISIS want" article have a decent writeup confirming that this is indeed among ISIS's big goals, with citations from ISIS itself.

Comment: I will say this is one of the goals of ISIS. Anti-Muslim backlash makes victimization narrative which in turn makes ISIS recruiting easier. Many recruiting by ISIS is facilitated by victimization narrative which is unfortunately present in Muslims countries whether they are actually victim or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about motivations, which are non factual -- or it is about a non notable claim.

Comment: For a moment I was getting angry at the close open rodeo. But here's the funny thing: The discussion that led to this last edit has helped me  already, so I won't. Just pointing out that the claim I make is made among others by the guardian so it might count as notable + I'm not asking you to guess Motivations but to check how this bt meshes with other (f)actual statements of Daesh. @Sklivvz is just plain wrong. Looks like its less painful to wade through Daesh publications myself than arguing with you guys here.

Comment: @mart everyone seems to claim that the intent of Isis is to divide people. This claim is not suitable for [skeptics.se]. No one seems to claim that it's an explicit claim by Isis, which makes this second claim not notable.

Comment: Oh please! Did you read the question? The text in the image is by ISIS, the claim to be checked is if this representative. All there in the question.

Comment: Can you remove everything else?

Comment: meta thread http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/can-we-reopen-my-question-about-isis-and-antimuslim-backlash